# Date function returns wrong value

Tags: excel

Simple formula in excel cell returns incorrect data.

I have a date in cell A2 and cell A3 has the formula

```
=Month(A2)
```

The cell is formatted as custom, `mmmm`.  Regardless of date entered, A3 returns January.

Comment: No, only =month(A2)

Comment: When formatted as general, I get an integer, as expected, something like 44900

Comment: Gosh darn it, I am sorry my bad.  Just do `=A2` and format the cell `mmmm`.  Month returns 1-12 and that equates to 1/1/1900 -1/12/1900  Which is why it is always January.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

U dont need to use =Month command you must to use =TEXT command it is better

```
=TEXT(A2;"mmmm")
```